# Why does FileSystem.DeleteFile method creates many thread when recycle bin has a lot of files?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I have a small question about the FileSystem.DeleteFile Method. 
So I have a software that create html files, before generating the files, I use FileSystem.DeleteFile method to move everything from the output directory to the recycle bin. However I discovered that when my recycle bin had a lot of files (about 10,000 previously), this DeleteFile method created many threads (up to 480) as in the screenshot, and the threads stay after this method completes. If I run again, I'd receive an OutOfMemoryException (I have 6gb of ram).

[image: high threads and memory usage]

However, after I emptied the recycle bin, my software ran smoothly with the threads being steady at around 25, memory usage didn't exceed 100 MB
[image: low threads and memory usage]

I've done many tests and I'm certain that there are no unmanaged objects in the code, and I am able to recreate the problem by filling up the recycle bin with heaps of junk files.

**Update**

```
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(txtPath.Text);
            string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(txtPath.Text);
            pb.Maximum = files.Length + folders.Length;
            pb.Value = 0;
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                FileSystem.DeleteFile(file, UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin);
                pb.Value += 1;
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            foreach (string folder in folders)
            {
                FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(folder, UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin);
                pb.Value += 1;
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Done!");
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but have you tried breaking in the debugger and seeing what all of those threads are actually doing?

Comment: @1800INFORMATION I don't have any thread in the code, they are created by the DeleteFile method and I don't know how to debug them.

Comment: Please provide your code as example i want tor run your code in my PC ...

Comment: You can still break into the debugger and examine those threads, for example by getting stack traces. You can use the publicly available symbols and source code from Microsoft to help you to figure out what they are doing.

Comment: Everything thing has limits - you just need to figure out a different way to accomplish what you want to do. "debugging" the OS seems like a waste of time - what are you going to do with what you learn?

Comment: First of all let us know if you delete files in one thread or in parallel. Second, turn off malware protection since it hooks file access methods and can scan them async. Third thing: reproduce thread blowing situation and suspend process with process explorer (Sysinternals). You will be able to examine thread stack than.

Comment: @BhavinPatel I've updated the post with the code I used to move files to recycle bin. Please note that I didn't use any thread for this method (although I know I should)

Comment: @PavPS I delete in the main thread, no threading was used.
- Disabling antimalware didn't help
- I used Process explorer to suspend the process and looked at its properties, majority of the threads are ntdll.dll!TpCallbackIndependent+0x238 
Don't quite understand

Comment: Environmental problem of course.  Other programs can call SHChangeNotifyRegister() to get notifications about file deletions.  You can't see these threads in the debugger unless you enable unmanaged debugging.  Shell extension handlers are the usual problem.

Comment: @HansPassant So you mean it depends on the computer's performance?